# Category page 404s on mobile but not desktop?

Tags: categories, themes, urls

I have a category `/blog` with one post in it. If I access `mysite.com/blog/` on a mobile device or in a mobile simulator it renders a 404 page. If I access this page on desktop it correctly renders the posts for the `blog` category.

This site uses a custom theme that I did not develop. What files should I look at to debug this?

Comment: Could it be a different condition in play - such as, you're logged in on the desktop so it works, but when you're not logged in (as on the mobile device) it throws a 404?

Comment: @WebElaine no. I can use my desktop browser and change it to 'mobile' by using the chrome inspector developer tools to reproduce. With the same session.